# How to suggest a tag synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I just made a suggested Wiki entry for [test-environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-environments).  I'd like to suggest renaming that tag to `test-environment` to be consistent with the related tag [development-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/development-environment) or create an alias, but since I don't have create a tag authority, I don't see an option anywhere to suggest an alias or rename.  Or is this the right place? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Proposing and voting on tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) is a privilege that requires 2500 reputation.

Typically, if you don't have enough reputation, you can post here on Meta to ask someone else to do it, and if someone with the privilege sees the need, s/he can suggest the synonym **if s/he has a score (upvotes-downvotes) of at least 5 on the tag**. At that point, the suggestion requires a score of 4 to become active. Any User with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag may vote on the synonym.

However, tag synonyms merely remap to the tag in a question. That is, if you type in [test-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-environment) in the tags field of your question, it will be remapped to [test-environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-environments). I believe what you're asking is for [test-environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-environments) to be renamed to [test-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test-environment) entirely, in which case you should ask a question here on Meta (as you have done) with the [retag-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request) tag.

If warranted, a moderator will rename the tag (and likely add the old tag name as a synonym to the new one).

Comment: Great, I'll just "hide and watch" to see what happens!

Comment: If I want to suggest a 'AAA' synonym with 'BBB', I need to have 5+ score on 'AAA' or 'BBB', or both?

Comment: And, is there a page I can see how much score I have for each tag?

Comment: @PaulLo You have to have a 5+ score on *the tag for which you are proposing the synonym*. So, if you want BBB to map to AAA when you type it in the tag field, you'd have to have a score of 5+ on AAA to propose the synonym; once you have that score on a tag, you can propose any synonym on it. You can see your score for a particular tag by going to the "Tags" section on your profile; it's the number in the box to the left of the tag name.

Comment: What can I do if I see two tags that are clearly synonyms of one another (like "emr" and "amazon-emr") but they are not tags I have asked or answered questions on or plan to ask any on (as this isn't my particular field), so will never obtain the 5 score needed to propose a synonym? I have the overall rep to propose synonyms but it doesn't look like I can do anything in this case.