# Add UFTPro synonym to the LeanFT tag

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

[Looks like I don't have enough privilege to propose a tag synonym for [leanft].](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277688/how-to-suggest-a-tag-synonym)

With this question I'm asking someone who has enough privilege to raise this proposal on the queue.

The reason being the fact that a while after LeanFT was launched, there was a decision to change the product name to UFT Pro. However, it's the LeanFT name that's mostly used out there.

In any case, since even officially ([on MicroFocus webpage](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/software/leanft)), the product is reffered to as  *"UFT Pro (LeanFT)"*, [the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leanft) should have the UFT Pro synonym.

Comment: How does this interact with the [tag:uft-api] tag? Are the products related? There is also a [tag:hp-uft] tag. How is that one different?

Comment: [hp-uft] is for [UFT](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/software/uft), the "mother" product. It is based on whole different architecture and programming languages, so it'll get different questions/people that can answer. And the uft-api tag... It shouldn't exist IMO.

Comment: Okay...so, does [tag:uft-api] refer to [tag:hp-uft] or [tag:leanft]? Or is it all mixed and confused?

Comment: uft-api refers to hp-uft (it's a small part of hp-uft), that's why it shouldn't exist. Or, with indulgence, it should be renamed to uft-api-tests

Comment: I tried to do this, but...honestly, I'm still confused. I need you to [edit] the question to explain which tags should be merged/synonymized with which other tags, or if you want them renamed, how they should be renamed. This is something that we don't want to screw up, so I need to make sure I understand correctly. Use the `[tag:tagname]` markdown to refer to a tag. That makes it even clearer. Arrows can show the direction of a merge.