# Why was [pythonista] made a synonym of [python]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

The [pythonista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonista) tag, which appeared to be used for the Pythonista iOS app, was made into a synonym of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) one day ago.

Obviously, this makes it difficult to find questions related to Pythonista, since any attempt to search on [pythonista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonista) is redirected to [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), a much wider category.

The old description was:

> Pythonista is an integrated development environment for writing and executing Python scripts on iOS. It supports most standard modules and includes many specifically designed for using with or automating iOS.

Which comports with the kind of questions asked using the tag.

Was this a correct decision? If so, why?

If this was not a correct decision, how does it get unsynonymed?

Comment: I can't see *why*, but the community must've voted for it to become a synonym.

Comment: And that must surely be a mistake, that should not be a synonym. I can undo the link, not sure what the damage'll be. It's only a day ago and today is Sunday, I suspect it'll not be much damage.

Comment: It was never a high-traffic tag, though very useful for those of us who use Pythonista. I did tweet the person who made the change. Is there a place were synonym votes are discussed?

Comment: My sincere apologies for the trouble I have caused. I suggested `pythonista` as a synonym of Python since the only definition I knew was _"Pythonista are programmers who are real loyal fans of  Python-the-language. "_. I was not aware of Pythonista for iOS.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf [Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pythonista/info) is always very useful to read.

Comment: So can a single person "by mistake" make the c++ tag a synonym of the c# tag on a sunday?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: To be honest, I've never like those "land grabs" from projects. Grabbing an already meaningful and commonly used term as the name of your project seems just bad manner to me.

Comment: No, [at least 4 persons are required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277689/2441442) @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I've removed the synonym again, as it was [suggested by mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373496/why-was-pythonista-merged-with-python#comment626824_373496):

> My sincere apologies for the trouble I have caused. I suggested `pythonista` as a synonym of Python since the only definition I knew was *"Pythonista are programmers who are real loyal fans of Python-the-language. "*. I was not aware of Pythonista for iOS. – lmiguelvargasf

The project is clearly distinct and generating enough on-topic questions to warrant its own tag.

Removing the synonym [restored the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pythonista/info), and because the tag wasn't merged, the [existing tagging has been preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonista).

You may want to [go through posts with the word pythonista posted in the past day](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pythonista+%5Bpython%5D+created%3A2018-08-31..&mixed=0) to see if anything needs retagging (I think there's just one such post).

So, all in all, because this was caught quickly the damage was limited!

Comment: Thanks for the update and the link to potential questions. It doesn’t look like that question is about Pythonista specifically, but about potential differences making post requests between Python 2 and Python 3; so I did not retag it.

Comment: @JerryStratton: then we are done here!