# Making [apple-m1] a synonym of [apple-silicon]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Almost all questions tagged [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) are not specifically about M1 as opposed to M2. Usually, the tag that the author should really have used is [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon). That tag exists, but it is much less popular - probably because people prefer the concrete M1 over the general, maybe due to Apple branding focusing on the M1.

In fact, among the roughly 20 questions I reviewed, there is at least one that specifically mentions M2, not M1, yet is tagged [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1): [TensorFlow: Why is the training of an RNN too slow on Apple Silicon M2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75495143/tensorflow-why-is-the-training-of-an-rnn-too-slow-on-apple-silicon-m2)

A systematic search shows that out of ~2.6k questions tagged [apple-m1], around 80 mention M2: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapple-m1%5D+m2. Around 30 don't even mention M1 at all: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapple-m1%5D+m2+-m1

Interestingly, there is no [apple-m2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m2) tag yet, despite M2s being out for half a year now.

All this makes me wonder whether we should make [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) a tag synonym of [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon). I don't have the required score of 5 to make that suggestion, so following https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277689/7483211, I'm posting here.

For clarity, I propose that [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) --- point to ---> [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon)

**Update**: Daniel Widdis raised in the comments that there is "Apple Silicon" beyond M1/M2 Macs, namely mobile processors in watches (https://apple.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Apple_processors).

That's a good point, however, in that case the tag wiki needs to be edited, as it currently mentions explicitly the "ARM-based CPU found in macOS systems" and hence *excludes* the other types of Apple silicon referred to by Daniel.

> Use this tag for questions related to Apple's ARM-based CPU found in macOS systems from 2020 onwards, known by the marketing term "Apple Silicon"

Based on a quick search, [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) currently seems to be exclusively used in the sense of the tag wiki. There isn't any mention of watches.

Comment: I haven't tried creating it (even on a question that it clearly about an M2 device, rather than an M1), but I wonder if [[tag:apple-m2]] would be flagged as "too similar" to [[tag:apple-m1]], and hence why it doesn't exist.

Comment: Though, if it's not *too similar* then preemptively making [[tag:apple-m2]] a synonym of [[tag:apple-silicon]] wouldn't seem like a bad idea either.

Comment: I'm not opposed to combining `-m1` and `-m2` and any future M-series processors, but I do think there is possibly a fundamental difference between the M-series (Mac) chips and the iPhone A-series chips which are also Apple Silicon.  Are they similar enough to combine?  I'd like to hear from an SME.

Comment: (And while I'm at it, there's the S-series "apple silicon" in watches, and lots of other ["apple-silicon"](https://apple.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Apple_processors) products beyond the M1 and M2.)  Do we want them all merged together?  Maybe?

Comment: @DanielWiddis I responded to your points in an update. Basically, the tag wiki specifically mentions only the M1/M2 CPUs, and that's also how it's used in practice.

Comment: What about `macos-silicon`? Very rarely are the questions about the actual CPU, and rather are about developing/compiling other software in macOS.

Comment: @OneCricketeer "Apple Silicon" is consistently used as the marketing term for their ARM processors, and the same chips on the M1/M2 SoCs are also on A-series iphone chips (in a different SoC configuration).  Apple Silicon crosses macOS, iOS, watchOS, etc. with a lot of commonality in the Mach/XNU kernel layer.  I'm generally in agreement with this request but want it to be made clear what it's describing and what (if anything) to call the A-series chips.

Comment: It's confusing to call Apple silicon "A-series chips", @DanielWiddis, because that's already a well-established category in the ARM world, where you have the *extremely common* "A-profile chips"; that is, members of the Cortex-A series.

Comment: I encountered these tags when people have problems compiling or linking Fortran programs in on their M1 or M2 Macs. None actually touched the specifics of the CPUs. Usually some conflicts with some libraries or compiler executables from the Intel architecture in the installed environment. Yes, also those with M2 are tagged \[[tag:apple-m1]\].

Comment: @CodyGray the A14 is an apple designed SoC with firestorm and icestorm cores. So are the M1, M1 Pro, and M1 Max.  Code written for any one will run on the other.  The same can be said for the A15, M2, M2 Pro, and M2 Max with avalanche and blizzard cores. I have solved macOS M1 programming problems by referring to ARM64 Q&A because the Mach kernel is the same as iOS.

Comment: @DanielWiddis: We don't have (or want) different tags for different Intel microarchitectures either, like [intel-alderlake] (the recent big.LITTLE desktop/laptop chip) vs. [intel-skylake].  We just tag [x86][intel][cpu-architecture] for questions about or related to specific details of the internals of an Intel CPU.  For questions about new features (like vector extensions) on some more recent CPUs, we have tags like [avx-512] or ARM [sve].  (There are/were a bunch of ARM tags like [arm7] and [cortex-m4] of very questionable value vs. more generic like [cortex-m].)

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer thanks for doing this research. It has been on my todo list to make this exact type of post for literal months. I just kept putting it off.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) should become a synonym of *something*, but [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) may not be the best target and itself should perhaps become a synonym.  I propose [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) (a synonym of [aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aarch64)) as the target for this family of chips.

The M1 and M2 are of interest because of the programming challenges involved in porting software from Intel-based chips.

The ["Apple Silicon" Overview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon) at Apple's developer documentation states:

> Build apps, libraries, frameworks, plug-ins, and other executable code that run natively on Apple silicon. When you build executables on top of Apple frameworks and technologies, the only significant step you might need to take is to recompile your code for the `arm64` architecture.

Further, that documentation is very clear that the **arm64 code** vs. **x86_64 code** distinction is the primary differentiator for apps intended to run on Apple Silicon as well as Intel-based Macs (image sourced from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/porting-your-macos-apps-to-apple-silicon)):
[image]

Using a [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) tag without using a corresponding [intel-based-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel-based-mac) tag for macOS seems silly.  The *code* involved is [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) and questions not about the code associated with these chips are off-topic.

Apple-designed ARM chips (under the "Apple Silicon" umbrella term) have existed for many years on iPhone, Apple Watch, iPad, iPod, etc.  Since software for those other platforms was always designed for the same chips, the porting challenges haven't existed: in fact, iPhone apps work without modification on the new M1/M2 Macs, and I have solved macOS M1 programming problems using [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) Q&A.

The M1 family is an Apple-designed ARM chip with Firestorm and Icestorm cores.  So is the A14.  The M2 family and A15 are also similar with Avalanche and Blizzard cores in different configurations.

"Apple Silicon" is more of a marketing term than a programming one, and the [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) tag should be sufficient for programming using the 64-bit ARM instruction set used by these chips.  There are already plenty of [M1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barm64%5D%20m1)/[M2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barm64%5D%20m2) questions in the [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) tag.

Having the multiple tags may be harmful: there are [250 questions about arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapple-silicon%5D%20arm64%20-%5Barm64%5D) with the [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) tag but not the [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) tag, reducing the visibility to experts in that instruction set. This is more than half of the [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) tagged questions.

If there is an M1- and M2- specific tag, I recommend it be focused on the specifics porting macOS code from x64 to arm64 (or building an app compatible with both), and think [universal-binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/universal-binary) (per above image) is appropriate for these.

Comment: Is there nothing at all special about Apple's implementation of ARM64 that might possibly be relevant? If there is, we could consider [[tag:apple-arm64]]. As someone who does embedded development with ARM processors, I would not expect to see questions about macOS among the questions about the ARM64 instruction set, but, of course, I completely understand that, technically, it's the same (or a very similar) ISA.

Comment: As an iOS developer I need to differentiate between an iOS app targeted to iOS devices (which are currently arm64), Macs with Intel processors, and Macs with Apple's own ARM chips. If the [tag:apple-silicon] tag simply becomes [tag:arm64] then it becomes ambiguous as to whether I'm asking about iPhones or Macs.

Comment: @HangarRash fair point, but an app targeted to iOS will run on an M1/M2 mac without alteration.  Wouldn't the Rosetta or Catalyst tags be sufficient?

Comment: @HangarRash I would also think the pair `ios` `arm64` vs. `macos` `arm64` should suffice?  If you feel strongly otherwise I recommend you post an answer with your proposal and reasoning so the community can vote between them.

Comment: It might be a good idea to update the `apple-silicon` tag wiki to clarify its scope and make sure it includes all relevant types of Apple Silicon.

Comment: A lot of apple-silicon questions aren't actually about the silicon, they're about some software package and quirks of getting it installed on ARM64 MacOS.  As @CodyGray says, those aren't interesting to people who follow the architecture tag because they're interested in assembly language, and are really just clutter.  Instead of creating a lot of work for us making a judgement call and un-tagging [arm64] on questions that should probably only be tagged [macos], it's better to have a tag to satisfy people who want to tag something specific to it being an AArch64 Mac and their mixed-ISA problem

Comment: Perhaps we make [apple-m1] just a synonym of [macos]?  But probably better to have some specific tag for it.  Probably [apple-silicon], if it's ok to "pollute" that tag with those questions.  (Does it have many [cpu-architecture] questions about the CPUs in iOS devices like Apple A15 and earlier?)  I think we can do without a specific tag for M1 or M2 performance experiments e.g. with Linux `perf` or MacOS tools to ask about its out-of-order exec capabilities or whatever, not about software running on it.

Comment: @PeterCordes porting software from `intel-based-mac` to `apple-silicon` is indeed the primary purpose of a tag such as this.  I argue that `apple-silicon` is not the correct tag for these questions, however.  Perhaps [`universal-binary`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/universal-binary)?  Feel free to propose an alternative answer so people can vote on it.

Comment: I guess a related question is whether things like "I have (some library) version whatever x86-64, and I'm getting this error when trying to build something that links it" is a useful question.  I've seen questions like that tagged [x86-64] and [apple-silicon], which as an x86-64 expert I have zero clue about because I don't do Mac stuff.  The answers typically tend to be `arch --something` in the right part of the build script, or reinstall.  Reanswering that for every specific library doesn't seem great, but OTOH a generic duplicate might be too generic.  But is there any tag those fit?

Comment: @CodyGray there are a few, you can't run vanilla Linux arm64 on Apple yet (https://asahilinux.org/2022/03/asahi-linux-alpha-release/). There is a nice chart of the number of Apple specific drivers/changes needed (including Core changes to arm64 Linux) to boot here: https://asahilinux.org/2021/12/progress-report-oct-nov-2021/ This disregards the UEFI support needed to boot in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Most of the questions currently tagged [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) are specific to issues with computers running macOS.

Apple M1/M2 have a thermal design for desktop/laptop (not important) but they also have a number of specific features not available in any other Apple Silicon offerings (watch, iPhone, etc). The M-series has a T2 security chip that handles keyboards, fingerprint sensors, 3rd party OS support and other features not typical in A-series devices. There is also support for the PCIe bus, Thunderbolt controllers, and additional image signal processors.

The [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) should be a synonym, but I don't think it should be [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64)/[aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aarch64). The [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) tags are too general and the [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) tag would not make much sense.

I don't think is much danger making [apple-m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m1) a synonym of [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon). But if there is a concern, maybe the creation of an [apple-m-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-m-series) tag for the macOS specific questions and making [apple-silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) a synonym of [aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aarch64) or leaving it as it is now.

Comment: Thanks for posting a competing answer. I agree that as an initial first step, `apple-m1` to `apple-silicon` is a no-brainer and you present a good argument for not going further to `arm64`.

Comment: The M-series does _not_ have a T2 security chip. That was an Intel Mac thing, where the x86 chip was treated like a co-processor. Now that co-processor is gone and the "security chip" became the Application Processor.